# .Renviron in project folder

Tags: r

If I put the .Renviron file into my project folder, does that get read and override an .Renviron file (and any environment variables)? Or do I need to put the .Renviron file into the home folder? I looked and didn't see this asked anywhere else. Sorry if this is a dupe.  thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[Managing R with .Rprofile, .Renviron, Rprofile.site, Renviron.site, rsession.conf, and repos.conf](https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/360047157094-Managing-R-with-Rprofile-Renviron-Rprofile-site-Renviron-site-rsession-conf-and-repos-conf)

> ".Renviron files can be at either the user or project level. If there is a project-level .Renviron, the user-level file will not be sourced."